# MySQL: <>1 works but =0 doesn't

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I send query like

```
SELECT id FROM private_messages WHERE to_id=1 AND opened=0
```

It doesn't return anything

```
SELECT id FROM private_messages WHERE to_id=1 AND opened<>1
```

Returns all results where opened=0. `opened` columns type is enum with "1" and "0" (default) values. Question is, why first query doesn't return anything?

Comment: what about this: SELECT id FROM private_messages WHERE to_id=1 AND opened='0' ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `opened` is an enum, you should write:

```
SELECT id FROM private_messages WHERE to_id=1 AND opened='0'
```

Enums are really just a set of possible strings. From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html):

> An `ENUM` is a string object with a value chosen from a list of
>   permitted values that are enumerated explicitly in the column
>   specification at table creation time.

Comment: The section on [Handling of Enumeration Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/enum.html#enum-literals) is especially relevant.

Comment: @PaulBellora Can you please create chatroom and invite me. (My rep is not hi enough to create) I got 1 more question.

Comment: @epic_syntax Make a new question.

Answer (score 0):

In ENUM fields, the strings you specify as input values are automatically encoded as numbers. In readable queries and output, the numbers are translated back to the corresponding strings in query results.

So, you have to use `'0'` instead of `0`.

When you use query in this way `SELECT id FROM private_messages WHERE to_id=1 AND opened='0'`, you are asking MySQL to return all values where `to_id=1` and `opened` has the index value of `0`, and not the string value.